# APACHE ro NGINX: how to translate rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$   index.php?apple=$1&bee=$2  [L]
```

that is my htaccess apache file

I'm a nginx newbie... no idea where and how to set this up

Comment: I feel you bro, I just use this converter because it's just too much headache. Does 80% of the job for you (you still have to tweak it a bit sometimes) https://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with this one:

```
# nginx configuration

location / {
  rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?apple=$1&bee=$2 break;
}
```

Also this is a really good tool that you can also check: https://winginx.com/en/htaccess